# How to import web service reference in Android by using Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, eclipse-indigo

I'm developing an android app and I have to import some web service references; currently I'm using **Eclipse Indigo** and I didn't find any import web reference option, so can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: web service references??

Comment: Needs more information in this question, i even dont know what you mean by "web service references"?

Comment: ok, see I've a service url's (.net web services) and i need to import those url's into my project and i need to use classes, methods from those service url's.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there isn't any method of automatically creating WSDL service references in Android.

Unfortunately you will need to define the classes and methods that access the WSDL services yourself.

If your web service is using SOAP then you may want to investigate http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/ as a library to assist you with making the service calls.

Comment: Not WCF 'm using web services

Comment: Ok, perhaps you are using one of the older .net technologies that support WSDL (web service description language). Either way I don't believe there are any extensions to Eclipse available that will read the WSDL and create the service references/classes for you.

Comment: ya currently i've used axis2java jar file and i'm getting option like "import web reference" but it won't work me in this indigo version gives error? so is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class DbRequest {

```
public DbRequest() {
}
public String sendDBRequest(ArrayList<NameValuePair> httpPost) {
    String result = "";

    String url = "http://www.YourURL.com/android/dbservice.php";//For Online Server
    //String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/dbservice.php";
    //String url = "http://192.168.1.4/android/dbservice.php";//For Local Server
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(httpPost));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = e.toString();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        result = e.toString();
    }
    return (result);
}
```

}

Replace the URL Address of your DB Service. It'll call it and will receive string as a result...

Comment: In my service url i've so many classes and methods in it so how can i use them in android app?

Comment: create instance of above class in your activity and call its function by passing httpPost pair list if you want to post some data which can be read at the webservice.

Do it like this:
DBService dbservice = new DBService();
dbsesrvice.sendDBRequest(httpPost);